# Insert java variable in html-styled jTextPane

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

I'm building a Java Swing interface in which I have a HTML-styled jTextPane, which I use for displaying the current system status. I want to be able to display a few Strings (which may change over time), while using HTML to set the appearance and placement of the text. I use the line of code below to display two strings of them in the jTextPane.

```
jTextPane1.setText("<html><font size=\"4\" ><b><center> String A here! </center></b></font><br><br><font size=\"3\" ><center> String B here</center></font>");
```

What I want, is to insert two Strings (A and B) so that I can change them over time. But unfortunately, I cannot find the syntax to insert a String anywhere. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your HTML code as `template` and use the placeholders `%s` for `stringA` and `stringB`. Then use `String.format()` to insert your strings. At the end set this in your TextPane.

```
String template = "<html><font size=\"4\" ><b><center>%s</center></b></font><br><br><font size=\"3\" ><center>%s</center></font>"
String text = String.format(template, stringA, stringB);
jTextPane1.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jTextPane1.getDocument().insertString(offset, stringToInsert, attributes);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some constant strings like:

```
    final String PRE_HTML = "<html><font size=\"4\" ><b><center> ";
    final String MID_HTML = " </center></b></font><br><br><font size=\"3\" ><center> ";
    final String POST_HTML = "</center></font></html>";
```

And you can set like:

```
    String strA = "String A";
    String strB = "String B";
    jTextPane1.setText(PRE_HTML + strA + MID_HTML + strB + POST_HTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.format`:

```
jTextPane1.setText(String.format("<html><font size=\"4\" ><b><center> %s </center></b></font><br><br><font size=\"3\" ><center> %s </center></font>", a, b));
```